# changing my iFrame to window size

Tags: iframe

First let me start by saying I know absolutely nothing about programming or code or anything.
So trying to explain this to me will be next to useless, I just need a solution.

Basically I need this (not sure what its technically called) from sketchfab: http://sketchfab.com/m5ji3fe1b

to display on my website covering the whole window size. (so if you resize the window, it will also resize to fit the entire page...)

Here is the embed code from sketchfab:

I managed to figure out how to make the width change to the size of the window by replacing the "854" to "100%" however, If I try the same for height, it doesnt work.

So if someone could please tell me the code that I could copy and paste into my website that would make this work, I would really appreciate it.

I am using squarespace for my website, if that helps at all.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer I found, hope it helps you:

"Instead of a code embed, use a Squarespace video widget, so it will remain responsive to sizing. Then try using spacer blocks to create columns and/or rows until you get the layout and dimensions you are looking for."